# Covergence of fractional Taylor series

Tags: taylor-series, fractional-calculus, generalized-functions

Let $f(x)$ be a function that is continuous and infinitely smooth on entire $\mathbb R$. Let's consider Taylor-Maclaurin series for this function:
$$f(x) = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(x_0)(x-x_0)^n}{n!}$$

Where $f^n(x)$ is n-th derivative of $f(x)$, and $f^n(0)$ is correspondingly the value of n-th derivative $f(x)$ at 0.

We can create continuous generalization of this series based on integral:
$$g(x) = \int_{0}^{∞}\frac{D^tf(x_0)}{\Gamma(1+t)}(x-x_0)^tdt $$
Where $D^t$ is t-dependent (fractional) derivative operator.

The question. Can we prove that for all x in the intersection of domains of convergence of both series and integral $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq C$, where C is some constant? (Or disprove, it is just my intuitive hypothesis).

Basically, if for given x both series and integral converge, the both converge to some numbers, therefore there is number that can express difference between such sums  $|f(x) - g(x)|$, the question, basically, whether this difference is bounded as function of x.

Comment: The answer depends on the used definition of fractional derivative. See https://yandex.ua/search/?lr=144&text=fractional%20Taylor%20seriesto , especially https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/lvazquez/calcfrac/docs/paper_usero.pdf to this end.

Comment: Let's function power series be defined as
$$f(x) = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(0)(x)^n}{n!}$$
Fractional derivative of function than is:
$$D^\alpha f(x) = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(0)(D^\alpha x^n)}{n!} = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(0)(\frac{\Gamma(n+1)x^{n-\alpha}}{\Gamma(n-\alpha+1)})}{n!} = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(0)\Gamma(n+1)x^{n-\alpha}}{n!\Gamma(n-\alpha+1)} = \sum_{0}^{∞}\frac{f^n(0)x^{n-\alpha}}{\Gamma(n-\alpha+1)}$$

Comment: This is a rather strange definition of the fractional derivative. For instance, it does not satisfy the composition rule $D^\alpha D^\beta = D^{\alpha+\beta}$. Even worse: it is not translation-invariant, and $D^\alpha f(x)$ is not really well-defined for $x \leqslant 0$.